# MoveFile vs Antivirus (Trend Micro Security) : ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c++, access-denied, antivirus, movefile

I have a problem when copying an "**.mdb**" file (Microsoft Access) with the function "**movefile**".
I use a C++ visual studio 2010 program. Code :

```
strTxt1 = "g:\\temp\\toto.mdb";
strTxt2 = "g:\\temp\\tata.mdb";

if (!::MoveFile (strTxt1, strTxt2))
{
    CString strError;

    int iLastError = GetLastError();
    strError.Format(_T("Error  --> %d"), iLastError);

    AfxMessageBox(strError);
}
```

Error :

[image]

I already check this post : [C++ MoveFile giving ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED inconsistently for directory moves on Windows Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352396/c-movefile-giving-error-access-denied-inconsistently-for-directory-moves-on-wi)
I already try the **MoveFileEx** alternative but i have the same problem.

Remarques :
1- when i disable my antivirus, I don't have this problem
2- If I put a breakpoint at the start of the error block (CString strError;) and I manually replay the movefile instruction after a short wait (2 seconds) the **movefile executes normally**.

I'm sure it comes from my antivirus, but I haven't found a way to prove it "formally".
I have already visited the log files of my antivirus, nothing is reported.

Comment: In such case, you could always retry the operation for number of times with a Sleep statement.

Comment: maybe your pc is infected with a virus that hooks on MoveFile api? it's just a guess. i'm really not sure.

Comment: Yes, it's infected, but with an antivirus software. Sadly, these things are a known issue. Please report this as a bug to Trend, they need to be made aware that their software breaks other software!

Comment: @EylM yes, It is an alternative but I try to avoid solutions based on "sleep"

Comment: @acegs I try a full scan, my PC seems to be "OK"

Comment: In the past I had Trend Micro Titanium too, and I often had that kind of issues. It is overprotecting your computer. The only solution I got was to whitelist the trusted files... Until I removed Trend Micro Titanium from my computer :)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes, i will report this.

Comment: @Fareanor Thank you

Comment: Obvious question first: do you have access to G:\temp? Can you rename the file with Windows Explorer?

Comment: @user253751 Of course and I have "admin" rights. This problem do not occur when i try "movefile" on **".txt"** files.

Comment: @user253751 OP said that it worked fine when disabling the antivirus protection so yes, he has the access.

Comment: are those file opened by database engine? Maybe some process keps this files in opened state in such case this error can be reported.

Comment: @MarekR  The files are not used by another program, are not open for editing, no program has a handle on my files. I checked everything with "processexplorer"

Comment: Maybe your antivirus detects an exe file with no signature, no admin rights to be executed, and seems to be not a legal software even though it's a simple exe. So other commenters are right that you a.) add your app to the whitelist of your antivirus for the time being and b.) report it to the company of the antivirus software you are using.

Comment: @acegs I have already tried to run my program in "administrator" mode and i had the same problem. Yes, i will add my program to the whitlist until the problem will be solved by the report services